# SBJsonParser: memory keeps increasing

Tags: json, macos, cocoa, memory, sbjson

I'm using SBJsonParser on a project of mine(due to the fact that I have to support Tiger). I'm using the version 3.0.4(it's the last non-ARC version). When I call this everything goes alright:

```
SBJSON *parser = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];
```

The problem is when I call this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Memory goes up and never goes down. If I release the dict, the app crashes. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Thanks!